# Classifying stationary points without the Hessian

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I can calculate the gradient which results in an expression of the form

$
\nabla_{\mathbf{a}} f=g(\mathbf{a})\mathbf{Pa}+u(\mathbf{a})\mathbf{Qa}
$

with $\mathbf{a}\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $\mathbf{P}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and $\mathbf{Q}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. With this, I can find an expression for the stationary points. However, when I try to determine their type I get stuck because the calculation of the Hessian is prohibitively involved. Is there any analytical tool for saying something about whether the stationary points are maxima or minima without having to compute the Hessian? I can plot the function when $n=2$ and I see that all stationary points are indeed maxima, except the case $\mathbf{a=0}$ which is a minima. My conjecture is that this is the case $n\geq 2$ but I haven't been able to proof anything so far... Any help or comment would be extremely welcome!

I am not a mathematician, so if something is not clear please let me know and I'll try to clarify it.

Thanks!

Comment: It does not look like the Hessian is going to be extremely involved. If I understand the notations right the Hessian will be something like $g(a)P+Pa\nabla g(a)^T+u(a)Q+Qa\nabla u(a)^T$. It should be Hermitian matrix if those $g$, $u$ etc are calculated correctly. Then you can check if it is negative definite at a stationary point for maximum.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You're right, that's the structure of the Hessian, but unfortunately, $\nabla g(\mathbf{a})$ and  $\nabla u(\mathbf{a})$ are very involved and calculating their gradient is not practical.

Comment: you could try to show that $f$ is concave / convex in a neighborhood of the critical points.